# How to get ID of clicked element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I have the following html:

```
<a href="#" id="#1" class="pagerlink" >link</a>
<a href="#" id="#3" class="pagerlink" >link</a>
<a href="#" id="#2" class="pagerlink" >link</a>
/*etc.... */
```

and the following jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var $container = $('.gallery_r').cycle({ 
        fx:     'scrollHorz', 
        speed:   500, 
        timeout: 0 
    }); 
    
    $('a.pagerlink').click(function() { 
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $container.cycle(id); 
        return false; 
    }); 
    
});
```

the 'pagerlink' links control are to jQuery Cycle slideshow. If I swap this line:

```
$container.cycle(id);
```

for this

```
$container.cycle(7);
```

It works. (obviously only navigating to slide number 7). So, my question is how can I pick up the ID of the link being clicked and pass it into that line?

Comment: `#` isn't a valid character in an `[id]`.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Your IDs are `#1`, and `cycle` just wants a number passed to it.  You need to remove the `#` before calling `cycle`.

```
$('a.pagerlink').click(function() { 
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $container.cycle(id.replace('#', '')); 
    return false; 
});
```

Also, IDs shouldn't contain the `#` character, it's invalid (numeric IDs are also invalid).  I suggest changing the ID to something like `pager_1`.

```
<a href="#" id="pager_1" class="pagerlink" >link</a>

$('a.pagerlink').click(function() { 
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $container.cycle(id.replace('pager_', '')); 
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: Numeric IDs are actually allowed in HTML5.

Answer (score 9):

You just need to remove the hash from the beginning:

```
$('a.pagerlink').click(function() { 
    var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(1);
    $container.cycle(id); 
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: The official spec says that IDs should always begin with an upper- or lower-case letter, never a number (or a hash sign). Many browsers will allow it, but you can't expect them to.

Answer (score 6):

@Adam Just add a function using onClick="getId()"

```
function getId(){console.log(this.event.target.id)}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your id will be passed through as #1, #2 etc. However, # is not valid as an ID (CSS selectors prefix IDs with #).

Answer (score 2):

First off you can't have just a number for your id unless you are using the HTML5 DOCTYPE. Secondly, you need to either remove the # in each id or replace it with this:

```
$container.cycle(id.replace('#',''));
```