# JQuery Get ID of clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this type of link in my HTML :

Librairy :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/js/jquery/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
```

HTML :

```
<a id='1' href='#' class='bulletinLink'> Bulletin du 11-01-2015 </a>
<a id='2' href='#' class='bulletinLink'> Bulletin du 13-02-2015 </a>
...
```

I want to get the id of this link when I click, this is my jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$('.bulletinLink').on('click',function(event){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
})
});
```

When I click in the link, it doesn't fire the jQuery function, what am I missing?

Comment: what do you mean by "i dont access to jquery function"?

Comment: Your code is correct, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Try some output. Print something right in the beginning of your function and maybe also print $(this). The code should work. Make sure your function (the enclosing one) is called at all. (edited punctuation)

Comment: i mean the alert method isnt called

Comment: Check console for any js errors. Make sure you included jquery library

Comment: Your code, copied and pasted and not modified in any way, demonstrably works: https://jsfiddle.net/z9zhrkbp/

Comment: Have you added jquery files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ID of clicked element with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838238/how-to-get-id-of-clicked-element-with-jquery)

Comment: yes, i'm using jquery-1.12.3.min.js

Comment: I've resolved it by changing the click like this : $('.bulletinLink').click(function()

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following simplified version, where you use `this.id` to retrieve the attribute `id` for your DOM without re-querying it.

PS: Make sure you [have included jQuery in your page](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp).
Example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.bulletinLink').on('click', function(event) {
    alert(this.id);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='1' href='#' class='bulletinLink'> Bulletin du 11-01-2015 </a><br>
<a id='2' href='#' class='bulletinLink'> Bulletin du 13-02-2015 </a>
```

Comment: I'm using this version :

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/js/jquery/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Pasja95 maybe you have an issue in including jQuerym maybe the path is wrong. Try instead to use this from CDN <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine with following code

```js
$(function() {
  $('.bulletinLink').on('click', function(event) {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='1' href='#' class='bulletinLink'> Bulletin du 11-01-2015 </a><br>
<a id='2' href='#' class='bulletinLink'> Bulletin du 13-02-2015 </a>
```

Comment: @Henak sorry, but why do you require the DOM using $(this)? It is not really necessary IMO.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add jQuery library...

Use this one :

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```