# How do I get the value of an element inside a click() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I am creating a list of all of my saved AI programs relevant to their name which is done like so and works fine:

```
@foreach ($ais as $ai)
    <a href='#' class='saved-ai'>{{ $ai }}</a> <br />
@endforeach
```

I then have a jQuery script which is designed to append the value of the name to an input box.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('.saved-ai').click(function() {
            $('#ainame').val(this.html());
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried to debug `this` to see what it held and why its behaviour was strange but I get this in my console:

```
<a href="#" class="saved-ai" name="Languages">Languages</a>
```

The error I receive is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.html is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (home:107)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (app.js:1)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.g.handle (app.js:1)
```

After researching, app.js in laravel already includes jQuery. However, It seems that `this.html()` does not exist. How can I get the value of the clicked element?

The expected output here would be `Language` gets placed inside the input box as the value.

Comment: `this` is the DOM node (the `<a>`) and not a jQuery object

Comment: This SO answer seem to fit your situation too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7838305/10864482

Comment: `this` is an DOM Element.  `html()` is jQuery method.  Not an Element method

Comment: The dupe target is for `.attr()` but it's the same error/problem/solution

Comment: Or just use the innerHTML and save a jQuery object instantiation

Comment: @Andreas thanks so much! I wasn't encapsulating `$()` around `this` which jQuery expects since `this` is indeed a DOM node! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing html for text, like so:

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.saved-ai').click(function() {
        $('#ainame').val($(this).text());
    });
 });
</script>
```

here you can find more about it: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: `text()` is probably a better method to use in my case, so thanks for advice. Thank you for pointing out that I was missing `$()` since `this` on its own is only the DOM node. Will mark when I can

Comment: Please vote to close as duplicate if there's a perfect dupe target available (like in this case) instead of adding the same answer again.

Comment: This is covered in the duplicate post.  Not downvoting since it's accurate, but still I agree with Andreas

Comment: Will do next time, I didn't read the comments before answering