# How to check if selectbox is grabbed and get it's ID with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to see if any selectbox is grabbed, with jquery, then get it's id from that, I have multiple boxes with the same name but a different id after, these are spawned via php. Ex. `number1` eg. number + integer.

I would like to check/register an event where on click of any selectbox the id gets grabbed and put into a variable for later manipulation.

kind of like

```
if ($('select').clicked) {
    var sID = $('select').getID();
    // use id to see which selectbox has been clicked.
}
```

The above needs to happen dynamically eg. we don't know the selectbox, so we need an event to check if ANY select has been clicked, then grab it's ID.

I have around 20 selectboxes, and don't want to make an individual check for them, as that takes up too much space, and more select boxes could come in the future.

> P.S. is this even possible?

Comment: What about `$(this).prop('id')`? `this` will be the clicked select element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get ID of clicked element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838238/how-to-get-id-of-clicked-element-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite easy with jQuery.
Use the [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method to attach a click handler on each select and grab the current clicked using `$(this)`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').on('click',function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="s1">
  <option>1</option>
</select>
<select id="s2">
  <option>1</option>
</select>
<select id="s3">
  <option>1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable is overwritten on each "input" event, so it is basically an alert of which one was the last `<select>` the user used. It will not trigger on being just clicked, the user must select a value and if the same value is selected as it was previously, then it will not trigger as well.

***Details are commented in example below***

```js
// Utility function for demo
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

// Reference the form
const form = document.forms[0];

// Register input event to form
form.oninput = xIds;

/* 
If you just want the last select user has used just declare a variable
*/
let x;

// Event handler
function xIds(e) {
  /*
  The select user is picking a value from
  */
  const active = e.target;

  /*
  If the select has the name 'x'...
  ...assign active id to variable x.
  */
  if (active.name === 'x') {
    x = active.id;
    log(x);
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-row::after {
  width: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.as-console-row-code {
  width: 100%;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id='x1' name='x'>
    <option selected disabled>Select an option</option>
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select><br>
  <select id='x2' name='x'>
    <option selected disabled>Select an option</option>
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select><br>
  <select id='x3' name='x'>
    <option selected disabled>Select an option</option>
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select><br>
  <select id='x4' name='x'>
    <option selected disabled>Select an option</option>
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select><br>
  <select id='x5' name='x'>
    <option selected disabled>Select an option</option>
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, this is not what I was asking for, however it helped me with the further part of my code, that's why I will upvote :D

Comment: Oops I was confusing it with another question! 

Comment: @mrx updated just for the id of the last select user picked a value from.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in jQuery.
first you need to add a listener on change event for all select box

for eg :

```
$('select').change(function(){
var sID = $(this).attr('id'); })

or you can also use 
    $('select').on('click',function(){
    var sID = $(this).attr('id'); })
})
```